Why is there a constant electric field in the collector region of my BJT?
My fellow semiconductor device physicists and engineers,
I am trying to simulate a simple NPN BJT using the Synopsys TCAD tool, Sentaurus. The BJT is biased in active mode, in the common-base configuration.
$\textbf{Relevant default parameters:}$
Out-of-plane dimension of the BJT = $1\,\mu \mathrm{m}$ (default)
$\mu_e = 1417\,\mathrm{cm}^{2}\mathrm{V}^{-1}\mathrm{s}^{-1}$  (default)
$\mu_h= 470.5\,\mathrm{cm}^{2}\mathrm{V}^{-1}\mathrm{s}^{-1}$  (default)
$\tau_e = 10^{-5} \mathrm{s}$   (default)
$\tau_h = 3×10^{-6} \mathrm{s}$ (default)
Thickness of the BJT (i.e., the vertical dimension) = 5 $\mu\mathrm{m}$.
$\textbf{Emitter}$:
Doping : (P-type, Aluminum dopant, $1\times10^{18} \mathrm{cm}^{-3}$)
Width = 10 $\mu\mathrm{m}$
$V_{\mathrm{E}} = -0.67235 \mathrm{V}$
$\textbf{Base}$:
Doping : (N-type, Antimony dopant, $1\times10^{16} \mathrm{cm}^{-3}$)
Width  = 10 $\mu\mathrm{m}$
Base contact width = 0.5 $\mu\mathrm{m}$
$V_{\mathrm{B}} = 0 \mathrm{V}$
$\textbf{Collector}$:
Doping : (P-type, Aluminum dopant, $1\times10^{15} \mathrm{cm}^{-3}$)
Width = 40 $\mu\mathrm{m}$
$V_{\mathrm{C}} = 1.0 \mathrm{V}$
From my understanding from standard texts such as Sze's 'Physics of Semiconductor Devices', we explicitly assume depletion approximation when deriving analytical expressions for the different current components of the BJT. The depletion approximation also allows us to infer that the electric field is zero in the so called 'quasi-neutral region', which is far away from the PN-junction.
Here is the problem. A Sentaurus (SDevice) simulation of the above BJT structure produces the band diagram shown below at the final bias. My questions are as follows

Why is there a constant field in the quasi-neutral region of the collector in my simulation?

Is this accounted for in the analytical expressions of the current provided in the standard textbooks?



At a first glance, this appears to do due to the low conductivity of the collector region, resulting in a constant series resistance in the collector. But I would like to hear what your thoughts are on this. Am I going wrong somewhere in the simulation?
PS: I did a similar calculation on nanoHUB.org. The name of the tool is called BJT Lab. I see similar results.


Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Given the resistivity of the collector and the current flowing, what is the voltage drop you would expect?
